# Why is image-src method-return-type instead of URL/route for Play Framework Module Controller?

Tags: scala, image-processing, module, playframework-2.3, broken-image

I have created a Play Framework module "Ean2BarcodePlayModule" which includes this template "barcode.scala.html" saved in the "views.barcodePackage.tags" package:

```
@(ean: Long)
<img class="barcode" alt="@ean" src="@controllers.barcodePackage.BarcodeController.getBarcode(ean)" />
```

After using "activator publish-local", I've then referenced this in the "index.scala.html" template of a test project:

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    @barcodePackage.tags.barcode(5010255079763L)

}
```

The expected result is

```
<!-- Redacted for brevity -->
  <img class="barcode" alt="5010255079763" src="/barcodeRoutes/5010255079763">
<!-- Redacted for brevity -->
```

But the actual result is:

```
<!-- Redacted for brevity -->
  <img class="barcode" alt="5010255079763" src="Action(parser=BodyParser(anyContent))">
<!-- Redacted for brevity -->
```

As will be noted, the controller's action method method's return-type appears where instead the source URL should be, but I don't understand why that is happening or know how to fix it.

The module includes this line in "barcodePackage.routes":

```
GET     /:ean   controllers.barcodePackage.BarcodeController.getBarcode(ean:Long)
```

Meanwhile, the route file in the test project contains:

```
->      /barcodeRoutes              barcodePackage.Routes
```

This is the code for the module controller:

```
package controllers.barcodePackage


import models.barcodePackage.Barcode
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

/**
 * Created by Brian_Kessler on 3/11/2015.
 */
object BarcodeController extends Controller
{
  def getBarcode(ean:Long) = Action.async{
      Barcode.renderImage(ean) map {
        case Success(imageData) => Ok(imageData).as(Barcode.mimeType)
        case Failure(error)     => BadRequest("Couldn't generate bar code. Error: " + error.getMessage)
    }
  }

}
```

Notes:

1. Most importantly, I'd like to see the module functionality working as expected.
2. But I'd also prefer a solution which allows me to successfully specify routes within the module, rather than be required to transcribe them all individually within projects which incorporate the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to Sarvesh Kumar Singh whose response helped put me on the right track, I've figured this out.

So, as I came to understand, the problem was not that the template was not finding the controller, but rather that it was calling the method in the controller instead of the reverse router for the controller.

So, what I really needed to do was tweak the module's template (all the other changes were probably irrelevant) to make sure it called the router instead.

With my present version of play, this meant changing barcode.scala.html to:

```
@(ean: Long)
<img class="barcode" alt="@ean" src="@controllers.barcodePackage.routes.BarcodeController.getBarcode(ean:Long)" />
```

Note, the source does NOT start with "@routes", but rather "routes" comes between the package name ("barcodePackage") and the controller name ("BarcodeController").

Answer (score 1):

That is because, your are calling this function by saying `@controllers.net.nowhereatall.playforscala.barcodes.barcode(ean)`, when template is being rendered by play.

Now as you have already specified a route and have bound it to your `controllers.net.nowhereatall.playforscala.barcodes.barcode(ean)` function.

Change the filename `barcode.routes` to `barcodes.routes`

Now, assuming that you have/want to integrated the `barcodes.routes` file of your sub-project in the main project as follows,

```
->  /barcodes barcodes.routes
```

So... now, you will need to change few things.

1. Move your controllers in `barcodes` sub-project under the package `controllers.barcodes`.
2. You should use `Barcodes` and not `barcodes` for object name ( Scala conventions ).

So your `controllers.net.nowhereatall.playforscala.barcodes` controller should ideally here - controllers.barcodes.Barcodes`. But you can place it here -`controllers.barcodes.net.nowhereatall.playforscala.Barcodes`if you want, just add the part`.net.nowhereatall.playforscala` everywhere in the following code.

Now, change the route in your `barcodes.routes`,

```
GET     /:ean                          controllers.barcodes.Barcodes.barcode(ean:Long)
```

Now, you need to do is to specify this route in your twirl template by using the reverse router.

```
@(ean: Long)
<img class="barcode" alt="@ean" src="@controllers.barcodes.routes.Barcodes.barcode(ean)" />
```

Now, when the tempate is reandered by play by `@barcodes.tags.barcode(5010255079763L)`, this `controllers.barcodes.routes.Barcode(ean)` call will be evaluated to `/barcodes/5010255079763` by the reverse router ( since you bound the `controllers.barcodes.Barcode(ean)` to `/` route ).

hence what you will get in browser is,

```
<img class="barcode" alt="5010255079763" src="/barcodes/5010255079763" />
```

You can even get it working by hardcoding the route as given below,

```
@(ean: Long)
<img class="barcode" alt="@ean" src="/barcodes/@ean" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer!    Unfortunately my test project won't compile because there is a problem with its routes file, possibly because I opted to include in my package name.  I'll play with it more tomorrow to see if removing that helps work as described above, though I'd like to be able to include such for the sake of having a distinct namespace.

Comment: The routes file is no longer causing a problem, but (1) I'm back to getting <img class="barcode" alt="5010255079763" src="Action(parser=BodyParser(anyContent))"> and (2) I realized your solution seems to remove utilizing the module's routes file from the equation (i.e. if I wanted to include multiple controls in the barcode module, they would all need to be transcribed into the test project.

Comment: Well... it is using your sub-projects route file, by adding this in your main project's route file  `-> /barcodes barcodes.routes`. If you have mutliple routes `/route1`, `/route2` in your subproject route file. they will be integrated as `/barcodes/route1`, /barcodes/route1`.

Comment: And did you follow everything written in the answer ?

Comment: I believe I followed everything correctly.  I've updated all the relevant code above.

Comment: I looked at your code again and realized I was missing @routes in my module template.  However, when I try to add it, the template won't compile, probably because we've renamed routes to barcodePackage.routes ... Not sure how to fix it, but I think the problem is with the code at this point, as hitherto, it has been skipping the router and instead including the value returned by the controller.

Comment: you were very close and put me on the right track, but see my answer.  :-)

Comment: Well.. my answer was complete... just that you chose the package name as `barcodePackage`and I chose `barcodes`, then I chose controller name `Barcodes` and you chose `BarcodeContoller`. And yes... I did one mistake while typing the answer, as the `reverse-routeer` is generated under tha package it self. So the it should have been `@controllers.barcodes.routes.Barcodes.barcode(ean)`

Comment: Actually... Play uses a heavily customized sbt build. And it generates a `reverse-router` for every package containing a Contoller, under the same package hierarchy as the controller it self. So... for any controller `me.mypackage.MyController` which has an action `myAction` bound to route `/myaction` the reverse router will be `me.mypackage.routes` and it will contain an object `MyContoller` which will have a method `myAction`. And this `me.mypackage.routes.MyController.myAction` method will evaluate to the bound route i.e. `/myaction`.

Comment: FInal answer as given below was to match the clarified code provided above, otherwise yes, it would have been as you now suggest.